# how to make a word go down to the next line if its too long for container?

Tags: html, css

Hi all:) i have a `<div>` wrapping words. the max length that could fit in it is 6 chars. I want to break it to the next line if word.length > 6
but go down to the newt line if word.length = 6.
e.g:

this is what i have:

```
text = "aaaaaaa"

|aaaaaa|
|a     |

text = "hi bbbbbb"

|hi bbb|
|bbb   |
```

this is what i want:

```
text = "aaaaaaa"

|aaaaaa|
|a     |

text = "hi bbbbbb"

|hi    |
|bbbbbb|
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`overflow-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Comment: `word-wrap` is a legacy name for `overflow-wrap`. The `word-wrap` is required for IE 11 and Edge 17- . Using both is best I think. The `overflow-wrap` will create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line.  The `word-break` does not have this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

What about split the words in two span inside of that div?

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
   <span>word1<span>
   <span>word2<span>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.flex {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

Comment: i don't know an advance what the length of the word is going to be. it's coming from the user.